# Python - string indices must be integers, not str - need help understanding data structure

Tags: python

My code looks like this:

```
    payload = base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data'])
    print("Decoded payload: " + payload)
```

In the log the result of the print line looks like this:

> Decoded payload:
>   {
>       "timeStamp": 1509835693.7319956,
>       "thing": "testing/23"
>   }

Wouldn't I reference the timeStamp like this:

```
payload['timeStamp']
```

I am confused by what I have in this data structure. Can someone please explain to me what I have here and how I access the data inside the variable payload?

Comment: Im guessing you have a string

Comment: Using `repr(payload)` gives a more helpful string including type information

Answer (score 5):

The decoded data is a string (as the error says), not a dictionary. You need to parse it before accessing its elements.

Considering your data is in JSON format, like the one you presented above:

```
import json

payload_str = base64.b64decode(record['kinesis']['data'])
payload = json.loads(payload_str)  # parsing
print("Decoded payload: ", payload)
```

And now you have no problem accessing `payload['timeStamp']`, as far as the JSON does contain this field.

Comment: Thank you for that...That makes a lot more sense...I am still a bit confused by the {} parentheses in my decoded payload output above.

Comment: @EricSnyder do you mean why there are `{}` around the data? That's a JSON object... take a look [here](http://www.json.org/), for example.